# WDIO : Error: Error: more than one config file specified

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I made some other config files and was getting this error 
-Error: Error: more than one config file specified .
So now I have deleted config files but wdio.conf.js now even getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

Got answer on this form @christian-bromann from gitter channel

https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio

It happens when one is calling wdio with more than one parameter,
only one is allowed.